# Settings what-opens-what once and for all (Backing up File Associations)

Tags: windows, windows-xp, backup, file-association

Every time I switch machines (as in, get a new one, or reinstall an OS or something like that) my precious file associations get lost. And the next six months pass slowly until I *again* set them up right.

Is there a program that allows me to:

- Set all the extensions I would like to open with let's say, Vim, without setting each one of them individually. Something of a kind: *Vim opens: .... list of extensions ...*

and/or

- A program which lets me backup my current settings, and when I copy those to a new machine it lets me just modify the paths where I putted the applications in question, and it does the rest (again, associates that program with all the extensions it opened before).

Answer (score 1):

File associations are kept in the registry as subkeys under `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT`.

The easiest way to set them is with the Contol Panel\Folder Options tool.

You can back them up by exporting the `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT` key like so:

1. Open the Registry Editor (go to Start->Run, type in "regedit")
2. Select the HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT key by clicking on it
3. Open the Back Up Registry dialog (File->Export...)
4. Under 'Export Range' select the 'Selected Branch' option, HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT
   should already be in the textbox
5. Type in a name for the registry file to export; perhaps "file_associations"
6. Select a place on your hard drive to save the file
7. Click 'Save'. That portion of the registry will be exported to that file

[image: Export Registry File]

To merge the keys back into the registry (like on a new machine) simply double-click the exported file and the keys will be merged into the registry, restoring your file associations.

As far as I know, there is no program to do this automatically.